# How do I calculate touch events relative to a bitmap drawn in an ImageView?

Tags: android

I have created an imageView, in which I draw a bitmap on a canvas. The ImageView is taller than the bitmap that I draw, so the image ends up vertically centered.

In the draw method, the top left of the bitmap is represented by coordinate (0,0), while the bottom right is represented by (bounds.bottom, bounds.right) (obtained using getBounds in the drawable class.

I am tracking the touch events in the ImageView. My question is, how do I calculate touch events relative to the bitmap drawn? I cannot find information on the draw position of the drawable to calculate the relative event coordinates.

For example, touching the top left of the bitmap would return an event at position (0,0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you know for sure that the image is centered:

y_coordinate_relative_to_image = touch_y_coordinate - (screen_height - image_height)/2
x_coordinate_relative_to_image = touch_x_coordinate - (screen_width - image_width)/2

If it's not also centered in the x direction, then you don't have to do anything if it's left justified. If it's right justified, then you subtract the difference in widths, but without the factor of two.

That being said, you might run into the issue described in:

[Android touch input: Coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6330802/1082887)

where the touch coordinates do not seem to cover the same range as the screen pixel resolution if you have your AndroidManifest.xml configured incorrectly.